# Change UIButton type programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have an UIButton made with IB, it is set to "Rounded Rect". At one point, I'd like to change the type to "Custom" in the code, is that possible ? I saw the type can be set at creation, but did not see if it was possible to change it later on.

Comment: Maybe make a new button, and swap them out?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, different button types are represented by different (private) subclasses of UIButton. That's why you can only set type at creation time but not after.

Comment: +1 `UIButton.buttonType` is a read-only property.  If you need to change the button type, then you need to create a new button.

Comment: Ok, I have created only one button with Custom type and added a default custom image that I programmatically change afterwards. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So if I want to create a UIButton subclass then how to set a type inside this class? buttonWithType: is not a solution for this case

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if I'll be much help, but for me it worked by doing:

```
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:(UIButtonType)];
```

example:

```
calculateButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

Comment: That will lose the reference to the button already allocated.

Comment: @PatrickBassut that is a valid point, and I think it could be fixed my  nil:ing the old button (correct me if I'm wrong)