# change button type programmatically

Tags: cocoa-touch, uibutton

Is it possible to change programmatically the type of button in Xcode?

I am trying to change the type from "Info Light" to "Info Dark".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. These button types are subclasses of `UIButton`, not settable properties. You can specify a type when creating a button in Interface Builder or when creating the button with the class method `[UIButton buttonWithType:(UIButtonType)buttonType]`.

If you want to change the button type, I would suggest creating a button of each type with the same frame, one with the `hidden`property set to TRUE. Toggle between them as needed by setting the `hidden` property. They can share the same target and action.

The question is a near-duplicate of this one:
[Change UIButton type programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107338/change-uibutton-type-programatically)